# Formatting list row based on score column Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have created formatted the list as a gallery. using two columns such as created by and score.

I was wondering if there are any way to do change the background color based on the score achieved. For example if the score is less than 25 its red, less than 50 to 25 its blue, and less than 75 yellow and above 75 its green.

please see the code below.

```
    // JavaScript source code
{
  "height": 98,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "display": "flex"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "p",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "sp-card-userEmptyText"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "=if(length([$Author]) == 0, '–', '')"
                  },
                  {
                    "forEach": "personIterator in [$Author]",
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'sp-card-userContainer', 'sp-card-userContainer sp-card-keyboard-focusable')"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'none', '')"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "img",
                        "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                        "attributes": {
                          "src": "=getUserImage([$personIterator.email], 'S')",
                          "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                          "class": "sp-card-userThumbnail"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(length([$Author]) > 5 && loopIndex('personIterator') >= 4, 'none', '')"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-userOthers"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(length([$Author]) > 5 && loopIndex('personIterator') == 4, '', 'none')"
                        },
                        "customCardProps": {
                          "formatter": {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "sp-card-personCallout"
                            },
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "forEach": "personIterator in [$Author]",
                                "elmType": "div",
                                "attributes": {
                                  "class": "sp-card-userContainer sp-card-userCustomCard"
                                },
                                "style": {
                                  "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') < 4, 'none', '')"
                                },
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "elmType": "img",
                                    "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                                    "attributes": {
                                      "src": "=getUserImage([$personIterator.email], 'S')",
                                      "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                                      "class": "sp-card-userThumbnail"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "openOnEvent": "hover"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "txtContent": "='+' + toString(length([$Author]) - (4))"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "sp-card-userTitle"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if(length([$Author]) == 1, '', 'none')"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Author.title]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "=if ([$Score.displayValue] == '', '–', [$Score.displayValue])",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Score.displayValue] == '', '–', [$Score.displayValue])"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your "Score" column? Number or anything else?

Comment: @GaneshSanap its numner datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background-color based on value of [$Score] like below:

```
"background-color": "=if([$Score] < 25, 'red', if([$Score] > 25 && [$Score] < 50, 'blue', if([$Score] > 50 && [$Score] < 75, 'yellow', if([$Score] > 75, 'green', '' ))))"
```

Add this to `style` property of element where you want to apply background color.

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, can you show me the full code as i cant get it to work

Comment: I don't have full code. But I can help you with your code. Where do you want to apply background color? To complete card or any specific button/span/div/p in your code?

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, I figured it out with the links provided.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Just wondering can we add a text (Bold)  below the score based on the condition

Comment: Sure, you can. you can add `p` or `span` element. set its `txtContent` property to the text you want to show and apply CSS like `font-weight: bold` inside its `style` property.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: You can add an element something like this: `{
                    "elmType": "p",
                    "style": {
                      "font-weight": "bold"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "=if([$Score] == 0, 'Fail', 'Pass')"
                  }`